# Mod_rewrite is not working in apache

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have configured apache http webserver 2.2.29 as a proxy. It's function is to redirect the incoming request to the backend server. Below is the flow.

Client sends a request using url `https://iproxy.company.co.uk:8443/cis1`. Apache instance is listening on `iproxy.company.co.uk:8443`. This request has to be sent to a backend server on url `https://i.company.co.uk:8443`. To achieve this I have used mod_rewrite. Below is configured in httpd-alias.conf file.

```
   `Listen iproxy.company.uk:8443
```

```
    ServerName      iproxy.company.uk:8443

    DocumentRoot    /app/
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*)$ https://i.company.co.uk:8443$1 [R=301,L]
    ProxyPassReverse "/products/widget/" "http://product.example.com/widget/"
    RewriteLog /app/instance1/logs/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 5

    ErrorLog "/app/instance1/logs/error_log"
    TransferLog "/app/instance1//logs/access_log"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4
    SSLCertificateFile "/app/certificates/star.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/app/certificates/star.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/app/certificates/rootCAChain.pem"
    CustomLog "/app/instance1/logs/ssl_request_log" \
      "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
   </VirtualHost>`
```

I have also configured the rewrite loggin to level 5. I am getting below in rewrite logs.

I am hitting below command to check if redirection works

`curl -k https://iproxy.company.co.uk:8443/cis1`

Getting below output

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
     </head><body>
    <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
     <p>The document has moved  <ahref="http://i.company.co.uk:8443/cis1">here</a>.</p>
     </body></html>`

I can also see below is printed in the rewrite logs.

`redirect to https://i.company.co.uk:8443/ci1 [REDIRECT/301]`

hence I am assuming that redirection is working fine. However.it is not..as server is not getting any request? am I doing anything wrong in the configuration.

UPDATE:
I have updated the RewriteRule directive by adding [P] at the end, which worked and my issue got resolved.

`RewriteRule (.*)$ https://sit-alfresco.rpmi.co.uk:443$1 [P]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the 301 response back to the browser which then will make that request.

This is not acting as a proxy at all then!

Does the browser even have access to i.company.co.uk (in which case why would you need to proxy?) or is that only accessible by the server (in which case a rewrite will not work)?

If you really want to proxy this then you should use mod_proxy with the following config:

```
ProxyPass / https://i.company.co.uk:8443/
```

Comment: Will ProxyPass be able to keep the uri same as the incoming request?I am expecting uri to be different for each request

Comment: The above config will display the contents of page https://i.company.co.uk:8443/cis1 at https://iproxy.company.co.uk:8443/cis1. And similarly for any other pages. So basically it maps the host. Note any absolute references on that page will remain as i.company.co.uk (though it's possible to get round this too). If that is not what you are wanting then I think it's best if you clarify your question.

Comment: it is working now for me.Thanks A lot. I have updated the question with the answer